# Check if css or js file on already opened page was loaded from cache or from the server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, caching

Is there any way to check from Google Chrome Console if a css or js file was loaded from the server or from cache (because it was already loaded) **on the web page that was fully loaded already**?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code, you could add a version number to the linked JS/CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1.0">
```

**?v=1.0**

This way you can see if version 1.0, 1.X or what ever has been load in your browser.